# character problem in webpart title after exporting a site

Tags: visual-studio, feature, site-template

After i have creat a site collection (in french), i save it as a model, open it in Visual studio, change the scope of a feature, package it and deploy it on the farm and create a new site collection from the new model, all the webpart titles seem to have a character problem.

For instance the **modified by**, **modifié par** in french is:

**ModifiÃ© par**

here are the steps

1. Create a Team site (in french)
2. save as a
   model(http://sitecollection/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx)
3. open the wsp in Visual Studio 2010
4. Change scope of the feature 3 from
   Site to Farm
5. Regenerate
6. Package
7. Deploy the newly created wsp to the
   farm
8. create a new site collection from
   this model
9. observe that the characters of the
   webpart titles have a problem.

note: my OS, SharePoint and visual studio are in French.

Answer (score 2):

Yep this isnt good. The problem is somewhere in the way SharePoint parses the XML the non 1033 (US) encoded text gets messed up.

The problem here is that the export tool inserts the translated text into DisplayName etc for your content types instead of the resource file link.

Eg.

```
<Field DisplayName="$Resources:Modified_By;" Name="Modified_x0020_By" ... />
```

vs

```
<Field DisplayName="Dokument ændret af" Name="Modified_x0020_By" ... />
```

The solution is to copy the resource links into your schema from other working schemas (you can either create list instances or similar in Visual Studio or copy paste from existing features in SharePoint root.

Comment: that sounds like fun!

Comment: but what if i have 1000 files to change?

Comment: Well thats how export works i'm afraid. I guess the resource tokens are resolved so you cannot extract those values once they are replaced with the localized text.  If you know what chars are affected, you could search out those values and replace only those with resource values. Since this is exclusively a problem for fields and views, you could also do a search replace on the fields and views found in SharePoint root that should have resource tokens.